# How should I resolve logic dependencies I have in a "flat" data structure?

Tags: c#, dependencies

I currently have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>` or dependencies.

The key is the properties name and the value is a list of dependency properties.

Here's a simple example:

```
{key: "a", value: ["b", "d"]},
{key: "b", value: null},
{key: "c", value: ["a"]},
{key: "d", value: ["b", "e", "f"]},
{key: "e", value: null},
{key: "f", value: null}
```

The `first` level dependencies look like:

```
a -> b,d
b -> nothing
c -> a
d -> b,e,f
e -> nothing
f -> nothing
```

After finding the first level dependencies the `second` level dependencies will look like:

```
a -> b,d,e,f (d has a dependency to e and f).
b -> nothing
c -> a,b,d (a has a dependency to b and d).
d -> b,e,f
e -> nothing
f -> nothing
```

The `third` and last level (in **this** case) will look like:

```
a -> b,d,e,f
b -> nothing
c -> a,b,d,e,f
d -> b,e,f
e -> nothing
f -> nothing
```

Now my dictionary has a lot more entries then I've shown in this example(Over a thousand).

My thought was to do something similar to angularjs's digest. I would create a threshold of let's say 10 or 20 runs. In each run, I'll check each properties dependency and update the model. If there was at least one update, then perform a recursive call.

I'm pretty sure this is a "known problem" with a better approach.

Anyway:

1. How should I approach this problem?
2. How do I know the number of levels I need to iterate until I will have no more dependencies.
3. How will I know if there's a circular dependency? I have lot's of data and it's not something easy to analyze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to write few recursive algorithms. Look here:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> _dependencies;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _dependencies = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            {"a", new List<string>{"b","d"}},
            {"b", new List<string>()},
            {"c", new List<string>{"a"}},
            {"d", new List<string>{"b","e","f"}},
            {"e", new List<string>()},
            {"f", new List<string>()}
        };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", DeepWalkDependencies("a", new HashSet<string>())));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> DeepWalkDependencies(string key, HashSet<string> alreadyVisitedKeys)
    {
        foreach (var d in _dependencies[key])
        {
            if (alreadyVisitedKeys.Add(d))
            {
                yield return d;
                foreach (var dd in DeepWalkDependencies(d, alreadyVisitedKeys))
                {
                    yield return dd;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Detecting a circular dependency can be achieved similarly. Instead of `HashSet<string> alreadyVisitedKeys` you need `List<string> currentPath` which will be re-created before every call to a recursive function. It is a good exercise to implement this algorithm. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've started implementing something a bit more efficient since I need better performance but you code does the job pretty code with minimum code.